# CMD Showing unsupported Characters

Tags: php, windows, command-line, composer-php, command-prompt

When trying to use composer,CMD is showing unsupported characters and Symbols.
I realised that composer is trying to show the colors in CMD, 
How can i prevent composer from showing colorw to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly are you using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout this Enable ANSI colors in Windows command prompt
https://web.liferay.com/web/igor.spasic/blog/-/blogs/enable-ansi-colors-in-windows-command-prompt

Comment: How can i install that files?

Comment: change directory to

Comment: and then run ansicon -i

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.